# PHP how to handle when there is no foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop that runs perfectly without flaw.

```
foreach ($row AS $row) {
   echo $row['id'];
}
```

There are times that there are no rows returned. I want to echo out 'there are no rows'; when there are no rows. The problem is if I try to do something like as follows:

```
foreach ($row AS $row) {
    if (!isset($row['id'])) {
        echo 'there are no rows';
    } else {
        echo $row['id'];
    }
}
```

It never returns the echo "there are no rows". I assume this is because when there are no rows, the foreach loop doesn't run. The question becomes, how do I echo "there are no rows" if and only if there are no rows while not interfering with the foreach when there are rows.

I have also tried code such as:

```
$row1 = $stmt->fetch();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if (isset($row1['id'])) {
        foreach ($row AS $row) {
```

Still no luck

So the desired outcome would be something as follows:

```
When loop runs:
1
2
3
4

When loop doesn't run:
there are no rows
```

Comment: check before the loop

Comment: ... with [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/function.count.php)

Comment: $row AS $row ? maybe $rows AS $row

Comment: @Deep I use $row AS $row all the time but that count() solution got me sorted :)

Comment: `foreach($row as $row)` means you overwrite the value of `$row`, by the way. Also whenever trying to understand truth in value in any language, [you should look at the truth table](http://php.net/types.comparisons). In PHP an empty array is `false`. So as long as the variable is initialized `if (!$row)` will suffice.

Comment: @Sherif OP never said `$row` was an array

Comment: @Phil True, I just assumed it was from context of the code `$stmt->fetchAll()`, but the same general advice still applies for checking the truth table.

Comment: @Sherif as I mentioned [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460622/php-how-to-handle-when-there-is-no-foreach-loop?noredirect=1#comment66242454_39460657), the object in question could be implementing `Traversable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should check before the loop like so

```
if(count($row)>0){
//foreach ...
}else{
echo 'no data';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Test if the array is empty:

```
if (empty($row)) {
    echo "there are no rows";
} else {
    foreach($row as $row) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this works great for primitive arrays, it wouldn't apply to something implementing [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/class.traversable.php) and [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/class.countable.php). Just something to keep in mind